# Why is std::uint32_t different from uint32_t?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

I'm a bit new to c++ and I have a coding assignment with a lot of files already done, but I noticed that VS2012 seems to have an issue with the following statement:

`typedef std::uint32_t identifier;`

However, it seems that changing it to

`typedef uint32_t identifier;`

gets rid of the error. There are no includes and this is in the header file. I noticed that the definition is in stdint.h. If that's the case, why is this code acceptable outside of VS (ie. compiles properly using g++) but is unacceptable in VS? Can anyone please explain this?

Comment: It's an error in VS 2010. I can't test VS 2012 because the UI was too unusable to leave installed.

Comment: I believe you need to include `cstdint` to get the one with the std namespace

Comment: @CodyGray the OP appears to be using VS2012, so the UI isn't that unusable.

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: For those coming here from a Google search, as I am, converting from Visual Studio 2015 to 2017: uint32_t, with or without std::, has a value of unsigned int in my 64 bit project.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The difference is that one is inside a namespace and the other isn't. Otherwise they should be the same. The first is supposed to be the C version and the second is the C++ version. Before C++11 it was mandated that including the prefixed versions instead of the C standard library version brings in all C definitions inside the standard namespace. In C++11 this restriction has been relaxed as this is not always possible.

It could be that your compiler defines this type implicitly. In any case, you should include `cstdint` to make the version in the namespace `std` available (and possibly the one in the global namespace). Including `stdint.h` should just make the unqualified version available.

Earlier version of Visual Studio shipped without this header, so this is bound to be troublesome.

Due all this madness, most people will fall back on a third-party implementation such as `boost/cstdint.hpp`.

**Edit:** They are the same and serve the same purpose. As a rule: If you want to use the version in the `std` namespace, include `cstdint`. If you want the one in the global namespace, include `stdint.h`. For C++ it is recommended to use the one in the `std` namespace. As a rule: Always include what you use and don't rely on other headers including things for you.

Comment: But essentially, their functionality is identical?

Comment: @Daniel Yes. I should have emphasized that more. All the talk about broken compilers is probably more confusing than helpful.

Answer (score 14):

`uint32_t` (aka `::uint32_t` i.e. the one in the global namespace) is declared in `<stdint.h>`. That header *might* also declare it in namespace `std`, as `std::uint32_t`, but it's not required to do so.

`std::uint32_t` (i.e. the one in namespace `std`) is declared in `<cstdint>`. That header *might* also declare it in the global namespace, as `::uint32_t`, but it's not required to do so.

> If that's the case, why is this code acceptable outside of VS (ie. compiles properly using g++) but is unacceptable in VS? Can anyone please explain this?

If you want to use `std::uint32_t` then you must `#include <cstdint>`, or the code may not compile.  If it does compile with G++ then presumably some other header indirectly includes `<cstdint>` but you shouldn't rely on that, include the right headers for the names you use.

Comment: Are `::uint32_t` and `std::uint32_t` guaranteed to be identical? Or can I run into trouble when mixing both types, especially when templates come into play?

Comment: They're guaranteed to be typedefs for the same type.

Comment: `<stdint.h>` is a C library header, I don't think it can declare anything in namespace `std`. When included in C++, C library headers, with a few exceptions not relevant to the topic, act the same way as they do in C, i.e. they declare stuff in the global namespace.

Comment: @AndreySemashev, wrong, see [\[depr.c.headers\] p3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/depr.c.headers#3) -- the `<name.h>` headers are allowed to add names to `std` as well as to the global namespace, as I said. [\[live example\]](https://godbolt.org/z/G_SKuV)