# Namespace in front of standard integral types

Tags: c++, stl, namespaces, std

What are the differences between writing `std::uint32_t` or just `uint32_t`? Has the namespace `std` been introduced here to solve some issues, or is it just a matter of taste? In which problem could I incur if I omit it?

Comment: @NathanOliver related, but that is not my question at all

Comment: @nyarlathotep108 Which part of your question is not answered by the linked question?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14883896/why-is-stduint32-t-different-from-uint32-t